# How to echo string to pdf

Tags: bash, pdf, echo

How do I echo a statement directly to a pdf via the command line?

I would like something like the following

```
cupsfilter -m text "Thank you for considering this question" > trial.pdf
echo "Thank you for considering this question" | a2pdf trial2.pdf
lpr -P "Thank you for considering this question" trial3.pdf
```

I am using Fedora25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `a2ps` and `ps2pdf`:

```
echo "Thank you for considering this question" | a2ps -B -o - | ps2pdf - trial.pdf
```